# WPF - Prevent ListView from losing focus

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, focus

I would like the selected item(s) in my ListView to remain focused when the user interacts with the Calendar control.

Currently when the user clicks an item in the list it becomes highlighted.
[image: List View focused]

When they click the calendar focus is lost, which I don't want.
[image: List View Lost Focus]

How do I prevent my Calendar from stealing focus from the ListView?
or
How do I prevent my ListView from giving up focus?

Comment: This question appears to be unclear. It's unclear that you want the listView to always have ***actual focus*** or you just want it to always have ***the highlight color***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot stop the calendar from receiving focus when the user interacts with the calendar

But you can effect the color of the ListView selected item when it does not have focus
You need to set the color of the ListView selected item not focused
These are set to transparent but just pick a color

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemNoColor" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
        <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
        <!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your two requirements are at odds.

By definition, when a user "interacts" with a control, they give that control focus. You cannot "interact" with the `Calendar` control, while the `ListView` control has focus.

You can certainly make `Calendar` unfocusable by setting `IsEnabled` to false (among other ways). You could also put an event on the `ListView` to "steal" focus whenever it is lost, but you would make interaction with other controls very difficult, and most interaction would be impossible.

You should evaluate *why* it can't lose focus and work around that requirement.